# Performance of Google chrome vs nodejs (v8)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome

[image]

#### Example

```
     console.time("Test");
     for(var i=0; i <2500000; i +=1 ){
             // loop around
     }
     console.timeEnd("Test");
```

The above code runs `faster` in `nodejs` than `google chrome`. Why node.js is faster than google chrome both are using `chrome v8` engine

#### Note

Average speed

```
 Google Chrome  - 1518.021ms 

 Node.js - 4 ms
```

Any idea about the difference execution speed?

Comment: How are you doing these performance tests ? How do you run the javascript in Chrome?

Comment: In your simple example the loop ultimately does nothing but change the variable `i` from 0 to several million. The V8 engine's JIT compiler will optimize parts like this and may not even run the loop at all if it can get the same result. As you can see, this will depend on the environment the JS is run in. This is a relevant JS talk on performance and benchmarking: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=65-RbBwZQdU

Comment: But when I am trying the below code in nodejs and chrome, then chrome is taking 522 ms and nodejs is taking 2277 ms. It means chrome is faster.
function test(){
    const startTime = new Date().getTime();
    for(var i=0;i<10000;i++){
        console.log(i);
    }
    const endTime = new Date().getTime(); 
    console.log('Execution time::' + (endTime - startTime )); // in nodejs Execution time::2277 and in chrome Execution time::522
    }
    test();

Answer (score 30, accepted):

In a web browser(Chrome), declaring the variable i outside of any function scope makes it global and therefore binds to **window** object. As a result, running this code in a web browser requires repeatedly resolving the property within the heavily populated window namespace in each iteration of the for loop.

In **Node.js** however, declaring any variable outside of any function’s scope binds it only to the **module** scope (not the window object) which therefore makes it much easier and faster to resolve.

We will get more or less same execution speed when we wrap the above code in function.

Comment: Also note how you get a significant speed-up by using `let i` instead of `var i`, which makes it a local variable.

Answer (score 6):

Its Due To **SCOPE** in JavaScript

> In **Browser** console **code without scope** :  Takes **lots** of time :  **Test: 1154.19ms**

below code will be kept in **heavily populated window object** which will take time to resolve;

```
 console.time("Test");
 for(var i=0; i <2500000; i +=1 ){
         // loop around
 }
 console.timeEnd("Test");
```

> In **Browser** console **code with scope** : Takes **less** time **Test: 3.06ms**

below code will be kept inside JavaScript scope and **scope will be almost empty**  so less time

```
function rocket(){
    console.time("Test");
     for(var i=0; i <2500000; i +=1 ){
             // loop around
     }
     console.timeEnd("Test");
}
rocket()
```

> In **Nodejs REPL** : code without scope : **Test: 14ms**

**Unexpected** But nodejs most outer scope contains some bunch of variables

```
 console.time("Test");
 for(var i=0; i <2500000; i +=1 ){
         // loop around
 }
 console.timeEnd("Test");
```

> In **Nodejs REPL** : code with scope : **Test: 2ms**

below code will be kept inside JavaScript scope and **scope will be almost empty**  so less time

```
function rocket(){
    console.time("Test");
     for(var i=0; i <2500000; i +=1 ){
             // loop around
     }
     console.timeEnd("Test");
}
rocket()
```

> **Conclusion :** Its all due to **SCOPE** and **SCOPING** in JavaScript is done by functions

Means if you create new function ,the **place** inside **curly brackets {}** is called as **SCOPE** and it will be empty initially, and if you create variable in this scope it will take no time to execute

Answer (score 1):

It's far from being as dramatic now, but I did get 2x boost from 5.417ms down to 2ms on your test. I had near absolute same values on Node and Chrome when I used a larger loop and a function wrap.

```
(function(){
console.time("Test");
for(var i=0; i <10000000000; i +=1 ){
     // loop around
}
console.timeEnd("Test");
}).call(this);
```