# Why is node.js runtime slower than Google chrome Console

Tags: javascript, node.js, performance, google-chrome, v8

We know that Chrome and node.js runs on the same V8 javascript engine. My understanding:

- Chrome should be slow, it not only handles the internal execution but also does **extra UI work**
- node.js should be fast, it has **no extra UI work**

So, was comparing simple speed test for node.js's V8 javascript

[image: Speed test on node.js]

With Chrome's V8

[image: Speed test on Chrome]

Why is node.js so slower than Chrome?

Btw, here is the code:

```
function speedTest(){
    console.time("loop");
    for (var i = 0; i < 1000000; i += 1){
        // Do nothing
    }
    console.timeEnd("loop");
}
```

Comment: Care to paste your loop code into your question so we can paste it into our REPLs?

Comment: I don't see any meaningful difference in performance between the two

Comment: 1ms could be anything.  This isn't a good test.  Add at least 5 `0`s to your number.

Comment: `time[End]` isn't part of V8 but rather is provided by the host environment. That could be part of the difference right there. Also, the version of V8 may be different. You'd be better off doing meaningful performance tests instead of an empty loop.

Comment: although this loop is a wrong way to measure performance since v8 will identify that it is empty and strip it out completely as part of its optimization logic

Comment: voted to close, cannot reproduce

Comment: I can't answer the question; however, the other answers don't shed much light on the matter. See http://www.jsbenchmarks.com/?anywhichway/lookup/master/benchmark.js/ for an example of how NodeJS and browsers differ dramatically. Note, although the browser result son this site are from multiple visitors and the Node results are from a single server, tests in an isolated environment show the same thing.

Comment: I think this answer will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29387950/performance-of-google-chrome-vs-nodejs-v8

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**TL;DR In absolute terms, it's not.**

First, those numbers are not 'different enough' to represent a real performance difference. Yes, in this trial they may differ by 25%, but *in the context of concern*, it's not significant.

Second, V8 is not doing the UI work in Chrome: compositing, rendering and painting are [done on processes and threads](https://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/multi-process-architecture) which are [dedicated to that purpose](https://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/displaying-a-web-page-in-chrome):

[image]

Third, node is faster than the browser on my tests, which at 0.5 to 1 ms is also meaningless. More importantly, **it negates the premise of the question.**

Comment: So, what does [the last question here](https://www.toptal.com/nodejs/interview-questions) is saying? Although it's vice versa, I was able to find the difference

Comment: @student It looks like a trick question on JS scoping rules designed for you to notice that the code block wrapping the console log is not a function (I assume? I don't know why I'd want to ask a candidate this question to be honest). It's  also not what you did in your example: you *did* encapsulate it in a function.

Comment: mind committing to this documentation proposal? http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/v8/commit

Comment: @tbodt Sure! I clicked Commit several times to no avail. I meet the declared criteria AFAIK.

Comment: @tbodt Done; I had to wait for there to be another question in `v8` within the last three days... http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/331643/why-cant-i-commit-to-this-documentation-proposal

Comment: In my experience, Node is grossly slower than Chrome in at least one instance. Creating a sizable object map (~5000 objects) is 125X slower in Node than in Chrome.
Parse a document of 50,000 words or more and add every word to an object (words["avocado"] = 1, words["banana"] = 2, etc.). If the word already exists, increment it; otherwise add it to the object map.
Chrome will do this in 100ms (in my app). Node (running on AWS Lambda) takes 12 to 13 seconds to do the same thing. I tried using an array instead of an object map, also a btree. in every case Node is about 125X slower than Chrome.

Answer (score 5):

Beware that;

- the console.log timers and in generals timers in javascript are not
  quite precise
- there are more features on the node V8, like the fs
- I don't think that the UI has something to do with the V8